# Switch case Java error in coding

Tags: java

I am an IP student. Tomorrow is my exam which has had Java. My PC got a virus last week and it has gone for repairing. So I can't practice Java in my PC. I want to know if the code I have written has any error in it because my friend told me that it doesn't seem good and looks wrong.

```
char eng=jTextField1.getText();
switch(eng)
case'a':
case'e':
case'i':
case'o':
case'u':
jTextField2.setText("It is a vowel");
break;
default: jTextField2.setText("It is not a vowel");
```

Please, help me out because tomorrow is ny exam and I have absolutely no time left.

Comment: Based on what you told us, it doesn't have errors.

Comment: Just a guess, but `jTextField1.getText()` probably returns a String, not a char. So that assignment at the start won't work.

Comment: Refer to the JavaDoc on the correct return types of your methods.

Comment: The formatting is a little unorthodox, and you're missing a couple of braces `{}`.

Comment: Just run it and see if it works...

Comment: Regarding the comment by @takendarkk, the first one you should ask is not some Internet community, but your *compiler*. If it gives some errors or warnings then you fix those first. Once it compiles cleanly you run it and test that it does what you expect it to do. If you have problems in either step and can't figure it out *then* you should come here and ask about that specific problem.

Comment: If you didn't see then please see that I have written that my PC is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char eng = jTextField1.getText().charAt(0);  //if you method return a String it gets the 1st character
switch(eng){
   case'a':
   case'e':
   case'i':
   case'o': 
   case'u': jTextField2.setText("It is a vowel");
            break;
   default: jTextField2.setText("It is not a vowel");
            break;
 }
```

But better way :

```
char eng=jTextField1.getText().charAt(0);
ArrayList<Character> list=new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add('a');
list.add('e');
list.add('i');
list.add('o');
list.add('u');
list.add('y');
if(list.contains(eng)){
    jTextField2.setText("It is a vowel");
}else{
    jTextField2.setText("It is not a vowel");
}
```

Comment: Just for my knowledge, how do u say that the latter one is a better way?

Comment: You can re-use the list later if you need